Floating navbar not sticking in place
I have a navbar react component that is floating and looks like this:

When I am trying to replicate this, my navbar tends to move to the right when the screen size is decreased by a few pixels.
<nav className="w-full fixed z-50 transition-all duration-300 ">
      <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 bg-neutral-50 dark:bg-neutral-950 rounded-full border border-border backdrop-blur-xl mt-5">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-4">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, magni.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>

The above code produces a navbar like this:

I tried adding a padding of 80rem on left and right side of the <nav> tag but it did not work. So, I tried by adding a max width but that did not work either.

You basically want navbar at center ?

Are you looking for a stick navbar on scroll?

@Meet yes but for some reason it is not working

@tacoshy i can but i have some other components that are in the same space

@chiragsolanki yes

in any case, I can't reproduce the issue you describe with the ode provided. Please post a [repro] that shows the issue

<nav className="w-full sticky top-0 z-50 transition-all duration-300 ">
      <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 bg-neutral-50 dark:bg-neutral-950 rounded-full border border-border backdrop-blur-xl mt-5">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-4">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, magni.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


@coders25 By adding this you class your nav will be stick at top

fixed that the OP used does this aswell and besides that, the code he provided works fluetly.

I know what fixed and sticky does. But you didn't achieve anything that was not working before. fixed would not cause a navbar to jump to flex-end. There is something different going on with code that the OP ahs not provided. unlike you. I actually tested the OP's code and therefor know that the code provided works flawlessly.
